# ExpertPDF Error: Could not get conversion result header. Data receive timeout

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation

I am getting an intermittent error calling GetPdfDocumentObjectFromUrl(url). The data for the report in the url is small and does not change much from day to day, and I am at a loss to determine the root cause.

Here is the stack trace:

An error occured   at ExpertPdf.HtmlToPdf.ImgConverter.GetMetafileFromUrlWithWebKit(String url, ᦔ[]& fonts, ᥱ& htmlParseInfo)
   at ExpertPdf.HtmlToPdf.PdfConverter.ConvertAndGetPdfDocument(String url, String htmlString, String baseUrl, String internalLinksDocUrl, Boolean fromUrl)
   at ExpertPdf.HtmlToPdf.PdfConverter.GetPdfDocumentObjectFromUrl(String url)
   at PCIScheduledUtil.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\fwork\v38Support\PCIScheduledUtil\PCIScheduledUtil\Program.cs:line 298

Description: Could not get conversion result header. Data receive timeout.

Any suggestions on what to look for are appreciated.

Comment: I'm having the same issue now.  Did you ever find a resolution?